# Did Harry Potter ever get on a Famous Witches and Wizards card?

Tags: harry-potter

Considering Harry Potter's fame, did he end up on a Famous Witches and Wizards card, possibly after the Battle of Hogwarts, or even before?

Comment: In most HP video games, HP has his own card: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Famous_Witches_and_Wizards_Cards

Answer (score 71, accepted):

## Yes

[HP Lexicon](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/source/other-canon/fw/) says that:

> Rowling says that Harry, Ron and Hermione were all featured on Chocolate Frog cards

This is the excerpt from the [relevant interview](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html) in 2007:

> Lecanard: Will we see harry and his friends having their own history on chocolate frogs cards
>
> J.K. Rowling: **Definitely, and Ron will describe this as his finest hour.**

As a side note, out of canon according to [this article](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Famous_Witches_and_Wizards_Cards) there was a Harry Potter card in some video games.

Comment: Ron considers chocolate frog card his finest hour. Ronbledore confirmed.

Comment: @DavidS the difference is that Dumbledore is just being modest. Ron really has nothing better to brag about.

Comment: @Kevin Depends how you read Dumbledore's character - I think he genuinely considered it one of his highest honours. And Ron has nothing else? To date he has: helped stop Voldemort from getting the Philosophers Stone, helped save the school from the Heir of Slytherin, been prefect, helped stop Death Eaters getting the prophecy, destroyed one of Voldemort's Horcruxes, was instrumental in the Battle Of Hogwarts (basilisk fangs) AND married the smartest (and it is implied, one of the prettiest) girl in his year. He's got plenty of fine hours, he just puts himself down a lot.

Comment: @DavidS ahem...and was a good Keeper

Comment: @DavidS "Headmaster Weasley" - That does have a rather fitting ring to it, don't you think? I can see Ron following in ol' Dumbley's footsteps.

Comment: @kaine Good catch ;)

Comment: The cards in the video games *were* written by Rowling.

Answer (score 33):

> Rowling says that Harry, Ron and Hermione were all featured on Chocolate Frog cards (BLC).
>
> <sub>[HP-Lexicon: Famous Wizard Cards](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/source/other-canon/fw/)</sub>

Trying to find a better source - where she said it. EDIT: See @N_Soong's answer.

Comment: Just beat you to it!  Sorry!

Comment: @N_Soong I just noticed! Congrats on finding the interview :). To delete the answer or garner a couple of rep points i wonder?

Comment: @CandiedMango A couple ... or a couple of hundred.

Comment: @randal'thor Best kept worst answer ever.

Comment: That's nothing - don't forget I got 120 upvotes for a similarly simple answer!

Comment: @randal'thor Yeah but there wasn't a similar answer posted just before yours which then got better ;)

Answer (score 3):

### Yes

This was confirmed by Rowling in an online chat

> **Lecanard**: Will we see harry and his friends having their own history on chocolate frogs cards
> **J.K. Rowling**: Definitely, and Ron will describe this as his finest hour.
> <sub>[J.K. Rowling and the Live Chat, Bloomsbury.com, July 30, 2007](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html)</sub>

### Content of the card

His card appears among the Chocolate Frog Cards featured in the EA Games [which were all written by Rowling](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85804/which-harry-potter-video-games-have-approval-and-oversight-from-j-k-rowling/119662#119662)

> [image]
> **Harry Potter**
> 1980 - present
> "The boy who lived."

His card also appeared (with more detail) as a Wizard of the Month on the [old jkrowling.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20110607100701/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/wotm.cfm).

> [image]
> **Harry Potter**
> (1980 - )
> The Boy Who Lived, only known survivor of the Avada Kedavra curse and conqueror of Lord Voldemort, also known as Tom Riddle. Harry Potter joined the reshuffled Auror Department under Kingsley Shacklebolt at age 17, rising to become Head of said department in 2007.