# Who was the Muggle Studies teacher between Quirrell and Burbage?

Tags: harry-potter

Unfortunately, to answer this question, we must assume the truth of something on the wiki.  It is these two statements on [the page of Charity Burbage](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Charity_Burbage):

> Her career lasted from 1993 to 1997.
>
> ---
>
> Burbage took up the post of Muggle Studies professor after a male teacher left.

Do we know anything at all about the male teacher who taught Muggle Studies between Quirrell (who stopped in 1991) and Burbage (who began in 1993)?

Comment: Guest Faculty??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Either he didn't exist, or nothing is known about him

Take your pick, really.

Having searched through the text of *Philosopher's Stone* and *Chamber of Secrets*, as well as Pottermore, [accio-quote.org](http://www.accio-quote.org/), and a broad-spectrum Google search, I can find no reference to any other Muggle Studies professors besides Quirrel and Burbage, except for one: the alleged Wikia itself.

According to [their own page on the character](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Unidentified_male_Muggle_Studies_teacher), he is *mentioned* only in the *Chamber of Secrets* video game (with some possible appearances in the films, almost certainly as part of crowd scenes where many unidentified faculty are present).

Although [Rowling is known to have had a not-insignificant amount of input](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85804/which-harry-potter-video-games-have-approval-and-oversight-from-j-k-rowling) into the video games, it's not clear to what extent she influenced *this* particular creative decision. The earliest reference to a Muggle Studies professor I can find is from some "idle jottings", allegedly circa *Prisoner of Azkaban*<sup>1</sup>, posted on her old website; I can't find this image on the archived text-only version (funny, that), but I found a [screenshot someone kindly saved](http://www.harrymedia.com/details.php?image_id=11784):

[image]

Although the professor is unnamed, it appears as though Rowling initially planned for them to be male, but then changed her mind and switched to female.

Since this almost certainly predates the *Chamber of Secrets* game, we're left with three possibilities:

- The reference in the game is a nod to this; either Rowling or someone involved in the production of the game decided to canonize Rowling changing her mind, by literally having the character change
- The game was in error, and it was not caught in time and/or not deemed significant enough to correct
- The game made this fact up, for reasons known only to themselves

However, this is the only information I've been able to find on the character. *If* he existed, this is the sum of the publicly-available knowledge on him.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that the name for the Divination professor appears to be "Mopsus"; Mopsus is an early character Rowling talks about in [an ITV press conference in 2005](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2005/0705-edinburgh-ITVcubreporters.htm), and suggests he got cut while writing *Philosopher's Stone*:

> [A]t one point there was a blind character who went by the name of Mopsus *[...]*  he sort of ­­ that was a very early character and he had the power of second sight, in other words he was a bit like Professor Trelawney, he was a very, very early character, this was when I was drafting *Philosopher's Stone*, the reason I cut him was he was too good.

So either my interpretation is wrong and the character of Mopsus was dropped later (merely cut from the final draft of *Philosopher's Stone*), or these scribbles are a good bit older than Rowling claims.

Comment: What does it say for Divination?

Comment: @CHEESE It's hard to make out, but I *think* it's the opposite: Rowling initially had the symbol for female, but drew the male symbol over it. If so, obviously she changed her mind back again

Comment: What about the name of the Divination teacher?  Doesn't look like Trelawney

Comment: @CHEESE Appears to be "Mopsus", an early character idea that eventually got dropped; see my edit

Comment: The most likely answer is that Burbage took over directly from Quirrell, and the game made up the other teacher.

Comment: Any word on what the names at the bottom were? They look like they must be DADA teachers. But surely we weren't in line to have Professor Pettigrew for year four?!?

Comment: @TheDarkLord Possibly a reference to [Enid Pettigrew](http://www.radiotimes.com/news/film/2017-10-18/harry-potter-what-was-cut/), an eventually-abandoned character. Or maybe she planned for Pettigrew to impersonate Moody, as I've seen some fansites claim

Comment: Ah, interesting. Could well be either scenario.