# JK Rowling and women's situation in magical society

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling

In the Harry Potter books, women in the magical cover very important roles, and  are equal to men from this point of view. This emancipation is similar to what has been quite recently achieved in our times (in UK, at least)

What is remarkable is that, when describing ancient magical society, JK Rowling seems to remark that this equality was real also in those times. Even when speaking about a century ago or before, women with powerful roles are cited.

I am also thinking about quidditch, which is the main magical sport and is played by both men and women on equal basis (at Hogwarts, at least).

I tend to believe this is a JK Rowling's specific choice. Are there any sources where she talks about this?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the fact that a witch cannot be considered "weaker" than a wizard when it comes to spell casting. Physical strength is not that important in the wizarding world, as it was in ours, because until 20th century, most work was hard labor. Thus emancipation developed when proportion of intellectual work increased and it became obvious that a woman can do no less work than man.

Comment: I suspect this question is a duplicate of [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/121598/51379). If the linked question doesn’t answer yours, you can try editing to clarify how they’re different.