# Did JK Rowling have any say in the development of Harry Potter: Hogwarts Mystery?

Tags: harry-potter

[As we know](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85804/which-harry-potter-video-games-have-approval-and-oversight-from-j-k-rowling), JK Rowling usually has oversight on the creation of Harry Potter-related video games.

But what about *Harry Potter: Hogwarts Mystery*?

First, [some](https://www.hypable.com/jk-rowling-opens-wizarding-world-to-new-creators/) have speculated that the brand's change in name (from JK Rowling's Wizarding World to Wizarding World) means she will withdraw from the future creation of new content.

Moreover, the game's content actually contradicts canon: whereas in *Wonderbook: Book of Spells* JK said that one could not fly using *Wingardium Leviosa*, here the main character/player's avatar actually tells one Ben Copper that the first step to fly on a broom was to "fly" thanks to the spell. Flitwick also say that historians trace the Disarming Charm's creation back to Merlin, thus contradicting *Book of Spells*.

On the other hand, the main character has visions reminiscent of those apparently had by Grindelwald in *Fantastic Beasts*.

Answer (score 6):

### Likely none.

Judging by [the game's website](http://www.harrypotterhogwartsmystery.com/)

> Harry Potter: Hogwarts Mystery is the first game in which players can create their own character and experience life as a Hogwarts student. The game will launch under Portkey Games, from Warner Bros. Interactive Entertainment, the games label dedicated to creating new Wizarding World mobile and video game experiences that place the player at the centre of their own adventure, **inspired by J.K. Rowling’s original stories.**

and the [press release on Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/news/experience-wizarding-school-with-new-mobile-game-harry-potter-hogwarts-mystery)

> The game has been created by Los Angeles-based mobile games studio Jam City, and will be part of the Portkey Games label from Warner Bros. Interactive Entertainment – you can read more about Portkey here.
>
> ‘As Harry Potter fanatics ourselves, we have great respect for the millions of people throughout the world who have followed the Harry Potter stories for more than 20 years,’ says Chris DeWolfe, co-founder and CEO of Jam City. ‘**This game is a labour of love for our developers and artists**, who are dedicated to creating the most magical entertainment and game play experience for everyone who adores J.K. Rowling’s Wizarding World.’

and the [press release on Portkey Games](https://www.pottermore.com/news/portkey-games-to-release-new-games-inspired-by-jk-rowlings-wizarding-world)

> As well as the familiar, you’ll also be able to visit new locations and explore new story elements, again, all **inspired by the wizarding world.**
>
> David Haddad, President of Warner Bros. Interactive Entertainment, says he is ‘thrilled’ by the new launch, and the games to come.
>
> ‘With Portkey Games, we are thrilled to answer the fans’ requests for more games inspired by J.K. Rowling’s Wizarding World,’ he says. ‘We are working with talented creators to build games that focus on player-generated stories, **which will live alongside the magical universe created by J.K. Rowling.’**

Everything seems to be "inspired" by the Wizarding World. There is no mention of direct involvement from J. K. Rowling herself.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/news/a-guide-to-portkey-games-place-in-the-wizarding-world), J.K. Rowling's official Harry Potter site,

> Each experience offered under Portkey Games will take place in the Wizarding World. **J.K. Rowling is supportive of Portkey Games and has entrusted the design and creation of the games to developers involved.** Developers can create a variety of new and unique gaming experiences that are all inspired by J.K. Rowling’s original stories so you may find some interesting new locations, characters, story elements, etc.

This means that J.K Rowling had no official say, but she is okay and she trusts Portkey Games.